How can I propagate the traceId between microservices/REST APIs
I wrote a Spring Boot REST API that uses micrometer to log the traceId & spanId, and I can even obtain this data in my @Service class through:
@Autowired
private Tracer tracer;
...
tracer.currentTraceContext().context().traceId()
tracer.currentTraceContext().context().spanId()

However, I don't know how to propagate this data when I call to another REST API.
Any ideas?
Get a concrete answer about how to propagate traceId & spanId between microservices/REST API calls.

Don't ask for "best practices". They don't exist and are merely opinions, and asking for opinions makes your question off-topic. I've edited it out.

Assuming Spring Boot 3, you can rely on the Micrometer Tracing libraries as specified in this Spring blog post.
Make sure to follow the official Spring documentation for any doubts. There is a section specific to propagating traces, and it's as simple as creating your RestTemplate or WebClient via the appropriate builder.
If you're still relying on Spring Boot 2 then the alternative libraries to use would be Spring Cloud Sleuth & Spring Cloud Zipkin.
